# Member "contains" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage ref[] storage ref

Tags: solidity

So I have 2 contracts and 1 inherits from other. First contract contains an array of strings and a function that look like this:

```
...
string[]  votes;

function contains(string memory _vote) internal view returns (bool success, uint i) {
    for (i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(votes[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_vote))) {
            return (true, i);
        }
    return (false, i);
    }
}
...
```

And the code in the second file goes like this:

```
import "./Standards.sol";   //<--|
                            //   |--  Imports everything just right
contract First is Imports { //<--|
...
function vote(string memory _vote) public  {
...
(bool success, uint i) = votes.contains(_vote); // <-- This line throws
...
```

The error i get is:

```
Member "contains" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage ref[] storage ref. [9582]
```

I would appreciate some help, I'm really stuck with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity does not have a `.contains` function/method.

Comment: Thanks! How silly of me, I tried to call a method as if I were using Rust